# Condition for quadratic form/refinement to exist

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, mathematical-physics

Suppose $a, b\in H^k(M, Z_2)$ are two k-cocycles on manifold $M$, valued in $Z_2$. We will assume $M$ to be orientable. For every such manifold, one can define the bilinear form $(a,b)= \int_M a\cup b$ which is defined only mod 2. Sometimes, one can also define the quadratic form of $(a,b)$, i.e. $q(a)\in Z_2=\{0,1\}$, satisfying
$$q(a+b)= q(a)+q(b)+(a,b) \mod 2$$
My question is

> What is the condition for $q(a)$ to exist?

In a special case $k=1$, I am aware that $q(a)$ exists if $w_2=0$, where $w_2$ is the second Stiefel-Whitney class of the manifold $M$. Then $q(a)$ depends on the spin structure $\sigma$, and sometimes one writes $q_{\sigma}(a)$ to high light the spin structure dependence. (Every orientable 2d manifold admits a spin structure. The emphasis here is that q depends on the additional data, i.e. the spin structure. )

> For higher $k$, does the quadratic form exists only when $w_{k+1}=0$? Then what structure does $q$ depend on?

Comment: I think what you call quadratic form is usually called a bilinear form, and then the refinement you mention is called the quadratic form. Perhaps there are multiple conventions. One special case in which it exists is for a $2k$ dimensional manifolds that is k-1 connected and stably parallelizable. I think in this case it is called the Wall form, and it is tied to surgery obstructions.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thanks! I changed.

Comment: Look at Algebraic and Geometric Surgery by Ranicki for a decent treatment. The main idea is that away from the Hopf dimensions, the quadratic form is obtained by using the above assumptions to change the middle homology to a group of immersed spheres, then the quadratic refinement is the self intersection number of the immersion.

Comment: And actually I think your suspicions might be on the right track. Browder has a paper called “The Kervaire Invariant of Framed Manifolds and its Generalization” where he is able to define a quadratic form on the middle dimension cohomology of a 2q manifold provided the q+1 Wu class is zero (these are intimately related to SW classes). The first half of the paper is not so hard to read if your know a decent amount of algebraic topology.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thank you for mentioning the Browder paper. If we apply to q=2, i.e. 4 manifold, then the criteria is the third Wu class u_3=w1 w2 vanishes, which in turn implies that w3=0 (if w1=w2=0). But the reverse if not true, i.e. there exists a manifold with w3=0 while w2\neq 0.

Comment: Yes, and for the Browder paper, the quadratic refinement only exists on a certain subgroup of the middle dimension cohomology. One way to guarantee the subgroup is the entire group is to be stably parallelizable (or to be somewhat more precise, the reason you use to show the Wu class vanishes should be because you picked a framing).

Comment: @ConnorMalin In fact, w1 being trivial already implies u3 is trivial, because u3=w1 w2= (\delta x)w2 = \delta (x w2) which is trivial. But what kind of structure does the manifold carry then?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what type of answer you want, but in Browder's paper he basically makes a rigorous notion of orientation that exists, if and only if, the necessary Wu class vanishes. So basically, the answer is that the manifold can be equipped with one of these orientations.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I see. Firstly thanks a lot! Here is the type of structure I am looking for: for example the spin structure $\sigma$ is the trivialization of w2, i.e. $w_2=\delta \sigma$, and it can be shifted by 1-cohomology, i.e., one can get another spin structure $\sigma+y$ from $\sigma$ by shifting by $y\in H^1(M, Z_2)$. Now we are trivializing the third Wu form, so I am looking for "something of degree 2", which can be shifted by 2-cohomology. One example is $x w_2$. But $x w_2$ contains more information than orientation $x$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin So it may not be fair to call this structure to be the orientation only.  I am wondering whether the object $x w_2$ has been widely studied and may have a name for it.

Comment: I think you probably know more about this than me, looks like a cool thing to look into!